# Loop over array with map() function onClick (ReactJS)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops

I want to create a wizard that changes content when the user clicks a "next" button.

I'm currently trying to use the .map function, it works but how can I adjust my code to loop over each step in my array onClick?

Currently, my code just displays 3 separate inputs with all of the steps in the array, what I want to do is iterate over each step onClick.

Here is an example of my code:

**Array:**

```
const wizardControls = {
    steps: [
        {
            step: 1,
            name: 'name1',
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'name1',
        },
        {
            step: 2,
            name: 'name2',
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'name2',
        },
        {
            step: 3,
            name: 'name3',
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'name3',
        },
    ],
};
```

**JSX using map() function:**

```
    {steps.map((step, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <input
                value={value}
                name={step.name}
                type={step.type}
                placeholder={step.placeholder}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </div>
    ))}
```

I'm thinking the button will need a handler function to loop over the index, however, I'm unsure how to do this with the map() function.

I'm open to a better approach if the map() function isn't the best route.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to start off showing index 0 only then when the user hits next show index 1 only, so on and so forth? This could probably be done with a `useState` to hold the current index to display and then without a map just use the index to render the data you want. When you click next just increment the index stored in the `useState`. You might need a bit of validation on the selected index depending on what else you intend to do with it to ensure that the array actually contains the index that is requested.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it. What I forgot to mention in my question is that the above array is already stored using `useState`. Was just having trouble understanding how to use map() and iterate onClick. - I appreciate your insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a step at a time, don't use `Array.map()` to render all of them. Use `useState` to hold the current index (step), and take the current item from the `steps` array by the index. To jump to the next step, increment the index by 1.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Demo = ({ steps }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [values, setValue] = useState([]);
  
  const next = () => 
    setIndex(step => step < steps.length -1 ? step + 1 : step);
  
  const onChange = e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    
    setValue(v => {
      const state = [...v];
      
      state[index] = val;
      
      return state;
    })
  };
  
  const step = steps[index];

  return (
    <div>
        <input
            value={values[index] || ''}
            name={step.name}
            type={step.type}
            placeholder={step.placeholder}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
        
        <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const wizardControls = {"steps":[{"step":1,"name":"name1","type":"text","placeholder":"name1"},{"step":2,"name":"name2","type":"text","placeholder":"name2"},{"step":3,"name":"name3","type":"text","placeholder":"name3"}]};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo steps={wizardControls.steps} />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is what I am attempting. - If you don't mind, can you add some notes for useCallback? Until now, I have not used that hook and need to wrap my head around it if I move forward with your solution. - I've already looked up the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) but still want to understand how you've used it in the context of this functionality. - Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `useCallback` is not strictly necessary here. The main idea is to preserve the function when the component is re-rendered, so the children won't be re-rendered as well due to the changing property (the function). It's a performance optimization, that can be skipped here.

Comment: Thanks. What would this look like without `useCallback`? In the snippet, it seems like it's used twice. - Not that I want this to be less optimized but if I were to do this with only `useState` would I simply remove `useCallback` from the code altogether? Sorry for the additional questions, I just want to understand this in case I have to fully refactor my app state.

Comment: The optimization is not really necessary here, just a habit from my usual project. I'll remove it, since it's distracting from the actual solution :)

Comment: I really appreciate it. I'll likely refer back to the way you utilized `useCallback` in your original answer on a future date.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this is by slicing by which step you're on (based on index).

Here's an example of what that might look like with your code.

```
const [step, setStep] = useState(1)

...

steps.slice(step - 1, step).map((step, index) => (
  ...
))
```

See a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-northcutt-el9w6

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. Thank you for taking the time to answer!